# Need help identifiying SOT23

Tags: identification, sot23

I accidentally killed a transistor in my HP Elitebook 820 G3 and need help identifying it. I searched the internet for about an hour and can't find the code that ist printed on the component to buy the correct replacement. It is located near the power connector.

I hope someone can help me by telling me what kind of transistor(?) this is.

[image: Picture of the transistor]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me, but that looks like a Cyrillic **d,** like 403д

Comment: are you sure it was SOT23?

Comment: and where this part? can you take a picture of your board and draw a circle where this part is?

Comment: thanks for the replies! I'm almost sure that its SOT23. I added pictures with the location on the board.

Comment: The Refdes starts with a D, suggesting a diode, not a transistor. Furthermore the proximity to the power connector suggests TVS (suppression diode). Did you by any chance have a power surge?

Comment: You can get a whole replacement PCB for perhaps less than $50. I couldn't quickly find any repair videos for that model that showed that side of the board, or any photos of sufficient resolution, so no chance of seeing it from them - have you tried searching?

Comment: OK, more googling - it's very likely to be a PJSOT24C (SOT23 housing): https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=pl&u=https://www.elvikom.pl/hp-elitebook-840-g3-6050a2822301-mb-a01-prosba-o-identyfikacje-elementu-t51119.html&prev=search&pto=aue

Comment: @AndrewMorton Marking codes don't match - the PN you gave has marking 2BC or 6BC. But will likely be a different PN of similar function - they are pretty interchangable.

Comment: TVS diode array sounds promising. I'll try to get Vishay GSOT24C. It's pretty the same as PJSOT24C.

Comment: @Nobi83 I suggest waiting until a few more people have commented - as Tom Carpenter pointed out, the package marking is different. If you knew who HP got the component from, that would be a good place to look.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PJSOT24C TVS diode. [Datasheet here - 'SINGLE AND DUAL TVS  FOR ESD / TRANSIENT PROTECTION'](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.es/datasheet-pdf/view/208582/PANJIT/PJSOT24C.html).

I found it via [this schematic for the HP Elitebook 820 G3](https://www.scribd.com/document/471518777/HP-ElitBook-840-G2-6050A2637901-MB-A02-pdf). Screenshot of the relevant section:

[image: Screenshot snippet of HP Elitebook 820 G3 schematic document]